# list items to be displayed using php code and array

Tags: php, html, list, dynamic, html-lists

I need to output the following html with my php code; the code works except the images are not rendering. I also want to display only four list items randomly, not all. I need your help to re-structure the code and the array. Please help.

```
<?php
function HTMLMenu($menu, $parentid = 0)
{
  $results = "";

  if ($menu.count() > 0) {
       $results .= "<div id=\"recommended-links\">\n";
       $results .= "<ul>\n";
       foreach ($menu as $item) if ($item["parentid"] == $parentid)
       {
            $results .= "<li>\n";
            $results .= "<p>\n";
            $results .= "<a href='".$item["url"]."'>".$item["title"]."</a>\n";
            $results .= "</p>\n";
            $results .= HTMLMenu($menu, $item["id"])
            $results .= "</li>\n";
       }
       $results .= "</ul>\n";
       $results .= "</div>\n";
  }

  return $results;
}


$menu = array( 

'1' => array('id' => 1, 'parentid' => 0, 'title' => 'Apple',    'url' => 'url-1', 'img' => 'img-1'), 
'2' => array('id' => 2, 'parentid' => 0, 'title' => 'Banana',   'url' => 'url-2',  'img' => 'img-2'), 
'3' => array('id' => 3, 'parentid' => 0, 'title' => 'Tangerine','url' => 'url-3',  'img' => 'img-3'), 
'4' => array('id' => 4, 'parentid' => 3, 'title' => 'Pear',     'url' => 'url-4',  'img' => 'img-4'), 
'5' => array('id' => 5, 'parentid' => 4, 'title' => 'Walnut',   'url' => 'url-5',  'img' => 'img-5'), 
'6' => array('id' => 6, 'parentid' => 4, 'title' => 'Ice Cream', 'url' => 'url-6',  'img' => 'img-6'), 
'7' => array('id' => 7, 'parentid' => 4, 'title' => 'Candy',     'url' => 'url-7',  'img' => 'img-7'), 
'8' => array('id' => 8, 'parentid' => 3, 'title' => 'Nectar',    'url' => 'url-8',  'img' => 'img-8'), 
'9' => array('id' => 8, 'parentid' => 3, 'title' => 'Honey',    'url' => 'url-9',  'img' => 'img-9') 
); 

echo HTMLMenu($menu);
?>
```

the desired html display

```
<div id="recommended-links">
    <p>Recommended</p>

    <ul>         
        <li>
            <img src="image-1" alt="" title="" class="imagecache" height="104" width="102">    
            <p>    <a href="url-1">Apple</a></p>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="image-2" alt="" title="" class="imagecache" height="104" width="102">    
            <p>    <a href="url-2">Banana</a></p>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="image-3" alt="" title="" class="imagecache" height="104" width="102">    
            <p>    <a href="url-3">Tangerine</a></p>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="image-4" alt="" title="" class="imagecache" height="104" width="102">    
            <p>    <a href="url-4">Pear</a></p>
        </li>
    </ul>   

</div>
```

want to display four list items *randomly*

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want all array items in a list menu (all items in single list) or in a menu with sub menu items (item with their sub items)?

Comment: want to render four array items (e.g. list items) within <ul></ul> randomly. there could be more than four array items stored. please refer to the html code.

Comment: Check my answer. I hope, that is what you want.

Comment: @AnayBose why do you keep asking the same question three different times?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page not rendering as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196956/page-not-rendering-as-expected)

Answer (score 2):

Your are not using the img in your array anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function HTMLMenu($menu, $parentid = 0)
{
   $results = "";

   if (count($menu) > 0) {
   $results .= "<div id=\"recommended-links\">\n";
   $results .= "<p>Recommended</p><ul>\n";
    $_menu = array_rand($menu, 4);
   foreach ($_menu as $item)
   {
        $results .= "<li>\n";
        $results .= "<img src='".$menu[$item]["img"]."' alt='' title='' class='imagecache' height='104' width='102'>\n";
        $results .= "<p>\n";
        $results .= "<a href='".$menu[$item]["url"]."'>".$menu[$item]["title"]."</a>\n";
        $results .= "</p>\n";
        $results .= "</li>\n";
   }
   $results .= "</ul>\n";
   $results .= "</div>\n";
   }

return $results;
}


$menu = array( 

'1' => array('id' => 1, 'parentid' => 0, 'title' => 'Apple',    'url' => 'url-1', 'img' => 'img-1'), 
'2' => array('id' => 2, 'parentid' => 0, 'title' => 'Banana',   'url' => 'url-2',  'img' => 'img-2'), 
'3' => array('id' => 3, 'parentid' => 0, 'title' => 'Tangerine','url' => 'url-3',  'img' => 'img-3'), 
'4' => array('id' => 4, 'parentid' => 3, 'title' => 'Pear',     'url' => 'url-4',  'img' => 'img-4'), 
'5' => array('id' => 5, 'parentid' => 4, 'title' => 'Walnut',   'url' => 'url-5',  'img' => 'img-5'), 
'6' => array('id' => 6, 'parentid' => 4, 'title' => 'Ice Cream', 'url' => 'url-6',  'img' => 'img-6'), 
'7' => array('id' => 7, 'parentid' => 4, 'title' => 'Candy',     'url' => 'url-7',  'img' => 'img-7'), 
'8' => array('id' => 8, 'parentid' => 3, 'title' => 'Nectar',    'url' => 'url-8',  'img' => 'img-8'), 
'9' => array('id' => 8, 'parentid' => 3, 'title' => 'Honey',    'url' => 'url-9',  'img' => 'img-9') 
); 

echo HTMLMenu($menu);
?>
```

Now this should generate random list item.

Comment: any four list items randomly. sorry I missed the word "randomly"

Comment: every time I refresh the page there should be four list items in a randomized fashion.

Comment: I have edited my code. It should generate 4 random list items now.

Comment: What is the value of `$k`? Where from it is assigning?

Comment: @ Jigar the code works perfectly. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

for the images part check that they are in the correct directory(in your case your document root directory)

for the second case if you want only 4 array entries you can delete the rest of the entries form the array

or you can use a `For`  loop insted to `foreach` loop to access only four items.

Answer (score 0):

```
change your function to the and make sure to check the folder where the images are located

function HTMLMenu($menu, $parentid = 0)  {


$results = "";  
$results .= "<div id=\"recommended-links\">\n";
$results .= "<ul>\n";

foreach ($menu as $item) 
   {


       if ($item["parentid"] == $parentid) 
       {
        $results .= "<li>\n";
        $results .= "<img src='".$item["img"]."' alt='' title='' class='imagecache' height='104' width='102'>\n";
        $results .= "<p>\n";
        $results .= "<a href='".$item["url"]."'>".$item["title"]."</a>\n";
        $results .= "</p>\n";
        $results .= HTMLMenu($menu, $item["id"]);
        $results .= "</li>\n";

       }
   }


$results .= "</ul>\n";
$results .= "</div>\n";

return  $results;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just change your foreach to for loop, like this

This loop will run 4 times and will get random items from `$menu` array

```
<?php
function HTMLMenu($menu, $parentid = 0)
{
   $results = "";

   if ($menu.count() > 0) {
   $results .= "<div id=\"recommended-links\">\n";
   $results .= "<p>Recommended</p><ul>\n";
   $menu_keys = array_rand($menu, 4);
   for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
   {
        $item = $menu[$menu_keys[$i]];
        $results .= "<li>\n";
        $results .= "<img src='".$item["img"]."' alt='' title='' class='imagecache' height='104' width='102'>\n";
        $results .= "<p>\n";
        $results .= "<a href='".$item["url"]."'>".$item["title"]."</a>\n";
        $results .= "</p>\n";
        $results .= "</li>\n";
   }
   $results .= "</ul>\n";
   $results .= "</div>\n";
   }

return $results;
}


$menu = array( 

'1' => array('id' => 1, 'parentid' => 0, 'title' => 'Apple',    'url' => 'url-1', 'img' => 'img-1'), 
'2' => array('id' => 2, 'parentid' => 0, 'title' => 'Banana',   'url' => 'url-2',  'img' => 'img-2'), 
'3' => array('id' => 3, 'parentid' => 0, 'title' => 'Tangerine','url' => 'url-3',  'img' => 'img-3'), 
'4' => array('id' => 4, 'parentid' => 3, 'title' => 'Pear',     'url' => 'url-4',  'img' => 'img-4'), 
'5' => array('id' => 5, 'parentid' => 4, 'title' => 'Walnut',   'url' => 'url-5',  'img' => 'img-5'), 
'6' => array('id' => 6, 'parentid' => 4, 'title' => 'Ice Cream', 'url' => 'url-6',  'img' => 'img-6'), 
'7' => array('id' => 7, 'parentid' => 4, 'title' => 'Candy',     'url' => 'url-7',  'img' => 'img-7'), 
'8' => array('id' => 8, 'parentid' => 3, 'title' => 'Nectar',    'url' => 'url-8',  'img' => 'img-8'), 
'9' => array('id' => 8, 'parentid' => 3, 'title' => 'Honey',    'url' => 'url-9',  'img' => 'img-9') 
); 

echo HTMLMenu($menu);
?>
```

Note: I have removed the line `$results .= HTMLMenu($menu, $item["id"])`. There is no need of that line to get 4 random items

Comment: rand value might return the same id again. :)

Comment: @Jigar Otherwise it wouldn't be random, would it.

Comment: @Jigar  Thanks for notify me, my mistake. Yes, you were right. I have edited my code. Thanks again.

Comment: `array_rand` will return random keys of array instead of actual random array. http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Also `$menu` will come instead of `$input` in array_rand.

I hope it helps you complete this code. :)

Comment: @Jigar Ooooopss That is really a disaster . I appreciate for your time and very greatfull to you to complete it Thanks.